# Offer BASIC authentication on NTLM fail

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, servlet-filters, ntlm

My application has NTLMv1 SSO implemented with jcifs .
I am using the NtlmHttpFilter as it comes with jcfis.

Everything works fine for clients that have the Network Security: Lan Manager authentication level set properly. This means that they send LM & NTLM responses, however it fails when users have levels that : Refuse LM & NTLM (Send only NTLMv2), which is expected.

My question is how can I configure the application so it asks for BASIC authentification for users that don't have the LAN Manager authentication level set (It is undefined by default) or they refuse to send NTLMv1 responses.
I tried to set the jcifs.http.enableBasic, and jcifs.http.insecureBasic properties to true, but I still get the following :

Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 - The parameter is incorrect.

**type** Exception report

**message** The parameter is incorrect.

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: The parameter is incorrect.
    jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
    jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:316)
    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
    jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:147)
    jcifs.smb.SmbSession.logon(SmbSession.java:140)
    jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.negotiate(NtlmHttpFilter.java:189)
    jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:121)
```

Do I have to implement the BASIC auth myself?

Comment: Hi i am also getting the same error, please let me know if u are able to find any workaround for this.

Comment: Hi! I gave up and changed the SSO implementation since NTLMv1 is not safe and outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, are u still using jcifs or u have switched to jespa, as the doc says,         https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html

Comment: Hey. I used waffle since it's free and it's a drop-in solution https://github.com/dblock/waffle.